# Populate Slack user profiles using external directory data?

Tags: ldap, slack, slack-api, directoryservices

My company has an existing user directory with usernames, email addresses, phone numbers, office locations, photos etc. It is available via a company intranet portal and also (I think) via LDAP.

Is there a way to configure Slack to pull this information into the user profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible.

If you use a paid tier Slack is offering directory sync functions out-of-the box. e.g. The plus tier has "Real-time active directory sync with OneLogin, Okta & Ping" (see [her](https://separatists.slack.com/pricing) for source)

If you are using the free version or don't / can't use the out-of-the-box functions, you can build it yourself by using the undocumented `users.profile.set` method in the Slack API to update user profiles including names.

Check out my [documentation](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.profile.set.md) on `users.profile.set` for more information.